# count number of files generated from split command

Tags: bash, shell

I want to work on the files generated by the split command. How do I count these files?

I am moving these to a separate directory, so it would help if someone could tell me how to store the output of `ls -1|wc -l` to a variable in a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you surround a command with backticks - ``command - the command is run and output replaces the quoted text.  This is called [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).  So you can store the output of a command in a variable like so:

```
COUNT=`ls -1|wc -l`
```

However, you don't have to store the output in a variable.  You can use the backticks in the middle of another command.  For example:

```
echo Split made `ls -1|wc -l` files.
```

Comment: Duh! you are half a minute ahead of me. You need to put in the ending back tick `

Comment: Answers with equal votes are no longer displayed in time order so it doesn't matter who's first any more.  But thanks anyway.  :-)

Comment: I could ve sworn I was trying the exact same thing and it wasnt working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
myvar=`ls -1|wc -l`
```

or

```
myvar=$(ls -1|wc -l)
```

They behave the same way

Comment: @Dennis: I agree, however, there are some old borne shell that does not understand $(..)

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is:

```
count=$(ls -l | wc -l)
```

to store the number of files in the variable count